# Do I need to move packages manually to 'public' folder every time I install them through composer?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I installed Bootbox package for modal dialogs through `composer require` and after that the package was saved into 'vendor' folder. However, I figured out that when including scripts in `<head>` tag, Laravel can only access fields in 'public' folder so I had to manually move my new Bootbox folder with script from 'vendor' to 'public' folder.

Now I want to install Popper.js package and include it in my layout view inside `<head>` tag. Do I need to manually cut and paste my newly installed package folder into 'public' folder every time I install package through composer? Is there an easier way?

Comment: composer is used for PHP dependencies, not for JavaScript ones. So I wonder what package you are using exactly?

Comment: @Namoshek I want to install packages the same way as in VS2017. I'm using Visual Studio Code and want to install packages for my laravel project.

Comment: I got that part, but also in VS you would use NuGet for C# dependencies and npm or yarn for JavaScript dependencies. So I wonder how you think composer is the right solution for Bootbox if it is a JS dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with `composer`. It is different from Nuget. You have several options

1. use the CDN. add it to your layout file or specific file https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js
2. download the production version of bootbox and put it in your public js folder, then add it to your layout file or a specific file.

I would go with the CDN option as it is fast and easy.